# Differences between io() and io.connect() using socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I would like to know what are the differences between

`var socket = io();`

and

`var socket = io.connect();`

using socket.io in my script (client side)

Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

There is no difference.

If you look at the source code for the SocketIO client, `io` is declared [as follows](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/c58ecfc4a7fc14c7fea5d93bb1610007ccac3303/lib/index.js#L15):

```
module.exports = exports = lookup;
```

And `io.connect()` is declared [in the same way](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/c58ecfc4a7fc14c7fea5d93bb1610007ccac3303/lib/index.js#L85):

```
exports.connect = lookup;
```

They both refer to the same (internal) function `lookup`.

I think that `io.connect` exists to make the client backward compatible with older versions of SocketIO.

Comment: It appears they are the same, although I came across a strange issue with my server where `io()` would connect to the socket service, whereas `io.connect()` would not. I cannot explain why. This is through nginx using port forwarding websockets